# Efficient Scrolling command log view in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a large scale project with many large user controls written in XAML/VB.net.

One main function of my software is to pass messages to remote device and display / use their response.

I have made a scrolling text panel our out of a text box with some modifications. For the most part, this works decently.

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of this, I believe (but i'm not positive.) That a component like this should be using virtualization by default and should only be rendering what's on screen. I see memory increase as more and more messages are passed in and they seem to come slower and slower after a significant amount are present.

Is there some correct way of implementing things such as in xaml? Are there any free resources that emulate something along the lines of command prompt as a WPF control?

```
<Grid x:Name="grdRoot" >
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller"  Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLog" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{Binding LogBackColor}" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ctxMenu}" FontFamily="Consolas" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True" FontSize="13" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" MaxLines="20000000" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>


    </ScrollViewer>

 <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="true" >
                </VirtualizingStackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Edit: I suppose I'm really using the wrong terminology. I'm trying to replicate a command line window, to show the passing back and forth of messages in an efficient way.

Comment: Appending all messages to a single `TextBox` is a poor choice because each update effectively concatenates the old text and the added text into a new string, and after a while this becomes a massive copy operation.  Better to use a virtualized `ItemsControl` and bind to a list of messages.  That way, only the messages in view will be populated.

Comment: Regardless, unless we see your 'enhanced' text box control, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I agree with @MikeStrobel another possible option is to add runs to TextBlock for each message.

Comment: Well in the back ground I use a string builder so its not exactly a direct string concat.

Comment: I generally use a `List<LogItem>`, where `LogItem` has a time stamp, and the text of an event.  I bind that list to a repeater with a template for `LogItem` to display the time stamp and text. When I add items to the list, I check its length, and remove items from start of the list to bring it down to reasonable number.  I also use a behavior that automatically scrolls to new items if the user is at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Wouldn't that just create an object for every line that is logged ? How do you handle copy pasting and highlighting from such a log?

Comment: @DanielMoss It does, and I don't.  It isn't something that has been required for me so far.  Virtualization takes care of the "having too many objects" problem though.  It might be possible to rig up selection on the log items, to select entire items at a time, for copy and paste.  It *might* even be possible to use a different template for selected items that uses a `TextBox` instead of a `TextBlock` for selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TextBox Solution

Performance will depend on how you're using your `TextBox`.  If you're doing something like this:

```
textBox.Text += latestMessage;
```

...then you're going to have poor performance, because those string concatenations are going to become *really* expensive after a while.

But if you're doing *this*:

```
textBox.AppendText(latestMessage);
```

...then you shouldn't see a slowdown, even with hundreds of thousands of lines.  Note, however, that you'll have a few restrictions, and you *will* need a custom `TextBox` implementation.

The first pitfall is that you'll need to avoid accessing the `Text` property.  You'll also need to avoid any methods or properties that could trigger the line metrics to be recalculated, like the various line/character offset methods (e.g., `GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex`).

The second pitfall is that you'll need to override the automation peer.  The reason for this is simple: if the Tablet PC Input Service happens to be running on the user's PC, this little gem will execute any time you append text:

```
var peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(this) as TextBoxAutomationPeer;
if (peer != null)
{
    if (e.Property == TextProperty)
        peer.RaiseValuePropertyChangedEvent((string)e.OldValue, (string)e.NewValue);
    /* ... */
}
```

As you can see, it forces the `Text` property to be read on any change.  `Text` is a lazy property that is *supposed* to only be computed on demand (though the code above throws a wrench into that).  Converting all the text ranges into a giant string on each change bring us right back to the first example, with terrible performance implications.  To work around this, we need to extend `TextBox`:

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new NoOpAutomationPeer(this);
    }

    private sealed class NoOpAutomationPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
    {
        private static readonly List<AutomationPeer> EmptyChildren =
            new List<AutomationPeer>();

        public NoOpAutomationPeer([NotNull] FrameworkElement owner)
            : base(owner) {}

        protected override List<AutomationPeer> GetChildrenCore() => EmptyChildren;

        protected override string GetHelpTextCore() => 
            AutomationProperties.GetHelpText(this.Owner);

        protected override string GetNameCore()
        {
            var result = base.GetNameCore();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                result = GetLabeledByCore()?.GetName();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                result = GetAutomationIdCore();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This should fix the problem noted above and also prevent the automation peer from computing the `Text` property under other circumstances.  Note that it may throw a wrench in your automated testing, if you actually use the UI Automation subsystem.  I've actually never used it myself *(cue gasps)*, so I don't fully understand the implications.

#### ItemsControl Solution

If you don't mind slightly constraining the user's ability to copy messages to the clipboard, you could bind a virtualized `ListBox` (or some other `Selector` with multiple selection support) to an `ObservableCollection` of your messages.  The item container generator will only keep enough containers around for the items that are actually in view, and if you enable container recycling, that should help keep memory usage down even further.  To enable recycling, you'll need to define a new `ItemsPanel` template:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

One trade-off here is that users will only be able to select *whole* messages, whereas a `TextBox` would them select any range within a message.  For most log-type screens, though, I think the coarser selection just makes things easier for the user, as they usually want to copy an entire message and not accidentally leave a few characters off.

Comment: Wow that is an incredibly detailed response. Thank you. Many of the messages passed back come in as fragments, so displaying whole messages is not really much of an option. I will use the first option.

Comment: I was just going to leave my earlier comments in place and not bother with a formal answer, but curiosity got the better of me.  Turns out `TextBox` can be quite performant when used the 'right' way.  You're quite welcome, and thank _you_ for sending me down an enlightening rabbit hole :).

Comment: I had an inclination I wasn't totally off base. I've used this code for over 4 years already and performance is generally pretty decent. Just looking for a way to prevent slowdown over time (some devices are very very verbose and dump tons of output into the logger, I had been manually cutting back lines to help with this.)